# Awesomium Browser Print to File

Tags: .net, awesomium

Is there any way to specify the file name when printing to PDF file. I can not find such a option. It only allows to specify file path not the file name

Answer (score 1):

If you use the OnPrintComplete event the PrintCompleteEventArgs parameter gives you a list of files that were created.

You can use this method to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

This code it's a possible workaround for that problem...

```
        int dev = 0;
        String path = "";
        String ruta = "";

        try
        {
            path = // Make a method to retrieve the file to save (savefiledialog)

            ruta = // Make a method to get the path without the file and extension

            dev = visorMapas.PrintToFile(ruta, Awesomium.Core.PrintConfig.Default);

            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(ruta + "\\doc_" + dev + ".pdf", path); // This will rename it!

                MessageBox.Show("Work done!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // Oh no!
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Bad thing
        }
```

So with that you will save the file.
I think it could be great if awesomium makes a method that accepts a file!...